# What type of column should I use for created_at and modified_at in Laravel Eloquent 2?

Tags: mysql, datetime, int, laravel, eloquent

Should I use DATETEIME? or INT?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I'm specifically addressing the

```
public static $timestamps = true;
```

flag set in Eloquent models.

Comment: Yes. No? Perhaps. Definitely. Are you storing dates, or are you storing integers? With the answer to _that_ question, _your_ question is solved.

Comment: Laravel offers the option to automatically take care of this with this variable set in the model : public static $timestamps = true; I'm trying to construct my tables to support this.

Comment: @JamWaffles Would you consider removing your downvote? Or explain it?

Comment: Gave you an upvote since this question is not as lame as JamWaffles answer sounds. There are different applications that use the unix timestamp for this. I don't wanna say whats good or bad about it, but they exist and so one should be allowed to question about.

Comment: Thanks. This isn't a question about what is best/worse/right/wrong, it's just a question about what the framework uses, seeing as I couldn't easily find it by googling or looking in the documentation.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Laravel only supports `datetime` for their timestamps.

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/769

Comment: check the pull request I linked as well ;)

Comment: I think it is downvoted because it is not as question which you can answer yourself with a look in laravel's well documented code. So, if you look inside laravel/database/eloquent/model.php and search for timestamp you will see, that there is a public function called timestamp(). Inside this function you will see that $this->updated_at is set with new \DateTime; So it is ever a good practice first to view if you can handle it by yourself.

Answer (score 7):

Just as an update: [The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12296190/2099674) is still valid for Laravel 3 and below,

but in Laravel 4 onward, it switched to supporting `timestamp` *or* `datetime` columns for `created_at` and `updated_at`.

[Here's a related issue on GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2696)

Answer (score 5):

Laravel 5 defaults is TIMESTAMP